# Azure Active Directory Single Sign-On

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

I wanted to know if there are provisions in SAML based Single Sign-On wherein I could authenticate using token provided by IdP and then once authenticated the authorization i.e. what roles/privileges the user has must be handled at the application end. This is entirely from an Azure Active Directory perspective.

Comment: For your specific query I have been gone through couple of analysis and figure out this for you. If you still have any more query feel free to ask. Thank you. Have a nice work around.

Answer (score 0):

**Provisions in [SAML based Single Sign-On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol)**

If users exist in your IdP but are not in your instance, SAML user provisioning can automatically create the users in your instance's User [sys_user] table.

> SAML user provisioning is supported for SAML 2.0 Update 1 when
>   Multi-SSO is enabled.

**How SAML user provisioning works**

When [SAML user provisioning](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/saml/concept/c_SAMLUserProvisioning.html) is enabled and the system encounters a new user that is not in the instance, the instance automatically creates a record in a temporary table with the name u_import_saml_user_, where  is an automatically generated text identifier. The system also creates transform map that specifies the data relationships between the import table and the User table. Each IdP in identified in the system has its own transform map. The transform map is created once for each IdP. Administrators can update it as necessary.

When the user logs in, they access an IdP to log in.

> 1. The system presents a list of all IdPs that are able to use SAML
>      user provisioning. If there is only one IdP that can use SAML user
>      provisioning, that one is used  automatically.
> 2. If none of the above conditions are true, the system uses the
>      [default IdP](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/single_sign_on/task/t_ModifyThePrimaryAndDefaultIdP.html#t_ModifyThePrimaryAndDefaultIDP).

**Administer SAML user provisioning**

To update the User table with the users in your IdP, you must first set up field mapping and then enable user provisioning through Multi-SSO IdP settings

**Roles/privileges**

For roles privileges and User administration you could refer [here](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/administer/roles/concept/c_UserAdministration.html)

**[Some Benefits of  Provisioning](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/sso_jit_about.htm)**

Implementing Just-in-Time provisioning can offer the following advantages to your organization.

**Reduced Administrative Costs:** Provisioning over SAML allows customers to create accounts on-demand, as part of the single sign-on process. This greatly simplifies the integration work required in scenarios where users need to be dynamically provisioned, by combining the provisioning and single sign-on processes into a single message.

**Increased User Adoption:** Users only need to memorize a single password to acces
s both their main site and Salesforce. Users are more likely to use your Salesforce application on a regular basis.

**Increased Security:** Any password policies that you have established for your corporate network are also in effect for Salesforce. In addition, sending an authentication credential that is only valid for a single use can increase security for users who have access to sensitive data.

To know some more idea You could also have a look on [here](https://www.gluu.org/resources/documents/articles/how-does-saml-work-idps-sps/)

**Some key resource for your reference**

1. [Configuring Azure AD as a SAML IdP](https://docs.datadoghq.com/account_management/saml/azure/)
2. [SAML Guide Line](https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/Beginner-s-Guide-to-SAML)
3. [How does SAML work? IDPs & SPs](https://www.gluu.org/resources/documents/articles/how-does-saml-work-idps-sps/)
4. [SAML terms and their purpose](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/teamforge178/action/saml.html)

Hope It would guide your way around regarding SAML implementation. Thank you very much.